# Ruby on Rails: passing conditional hidden values with form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In short: I have form that has 2 text fields for values :title and :title_de. I need to automatically pass value :lang on submit as either "eng" or "de" depending on if field for :title was left empty or not. How to do it?

EDIT: controller code for create:

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)

  if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Solution to assign `lang` in controller:

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)

  @article.lang = params[:title].blank? ? "de" : "eng"

  if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Or, if you prefer, you could use javascript/jquery to get the value of `:title` and then assign the correct value to `:lang` before submitting your form.

Snippet:

```js
$('#my-button').on('click', function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var title = $('#title').val();

  if(title == "") {
    $('#lang').val("de");
  } else {
    $('#lang').val("eng");
  }
  
  // change to $('#my-form').submit();
  alert($('#lang').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="my-form">
  title: <input type="text"name="title" id="title"/><br>
  title_de: <input type="text" name="title_de" id="title_de"/><br>
  <input type="hidden" id="lang" name="lang" />
  <input type="submit" id="my-button" />
</form>
```

Comment: The controller solution seems to put "de" in lang regardless of title being empty or not.

Comment: fixed it by changing line to:
`@article.lang = @article.title.blank? ? 'rus' : 'eng'`

Comment: If you created your form with rails helper methods all form values will be grouped together (most likely under the model/object name), so instead of using `params[:title].blank?` you could use something like `params[:article][:title].blank?`. But i like your fix better than calling params.

Answer (score 0):

When a form field is left empty it returns nil. You can check for nil and set the language in your controller:

```
if params[:title] == "nil"
# set the language
else 
# title is not nil, do something else
end
```

You could do it in the view as well using javascript but if the user has javascript disabled you have a problem.

Comment: Not sure how to implement this into my controller. Edited main post and added what I'm using there.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript you can do like

```
In your view add hidden_file_tag
<%= hidden_filed_tag :langauge, id: "langauge" %>

and in javascript
$('#title').on("change",function(){
  if($(this).val() == ""){
    $("#langauge").val('eng')
  }else{
    $("#langauge").val('de')
  }
});
```